# Accessing word docs on Sharepoint site. Are files cached locally?

Tags: security

My client wants users to access word and excel docs through the company SharePoint site from remote locations, however he does not want them to have access to the files after they have logged off the remote connection, for fear of unauthorized people accessing the information.

Are files which are accessed through SharePoint (using a locally installed version of MS Office) cached on the user's laptop/PC, and accessible afterwards?

Would appreciate any help.

Billy.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing stopping a user from clicking "Save as..."

Even if you disable client integration in Central Admin and make the default open behavior to open a document in the browser through Office Web Apps, the end user can still download a copy locally.